# Docker blocking connection from remote for a single specific port?

Tags: iptables, docker

I have a server with two docker containers, each with their own PostgreSQL databases.
One container is mapped to port 32772 and the other to 32771. These two databases used to be acessible by remote uses, and worked perfectly simultaneously. Until we had a forced shutdown of the machine.

The previous admin set up a system so that docker would start on startup and so would the 32771's container. I manually restarted 32772 container using `docker start`. Now the weird shenanigans began.

Both can be reached by `psql` and `nc` when in the current machine, while only database 32771 can be reached from a remote machine.

Both containers use the official postgres image, and the only difference between them (besides database data) is that they are in different docker networks, so I'm at a lost for what is causing this change in behavior.

I looked in `iptables` and cannot spot any weird behavior. Both ports are marked as listening in ipv4 and ipv6. 32772's `pga_conf.hba` and `postgresql.conf` are properly configured. There is no failed connection attempt in the database log.  Any idea what could cause that behavior?

Some logs:

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:7687
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:7474
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:postgresql

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS        PORTS                                            NAMES
3d001590ef69   postgis/postgis   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 months ago   Up 2 hours    0.0.0.0:32772->5432/tcp, :::32772->5432/tcp      postgis
6273d983556f   postgres          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 months ago   Up 2 months   0.0.0.0:32771->5432/tcp, :::32771->5432/tcp      pg_container
3714a16b6263   dpage/pgadmin4    "/entrypoint.sh"         20 months ago   Up 2 months   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp, :::5050->80/tcp   pgadmin4_container
```

docker network list

```
49a50a34254d   bridge            bridge    local
db7b6beb29cd   host              host      local
cc7bc4c85bbd   none              null      local
36ae3773e28d   pgadmin_default   bridge    local
```